# Does the verb to "resolve" collocate with "situation"?

Tags: word-usage, collocation

To [resolve](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resolve) means:

> to find an answer or solution to (something) : to settle or solve (something)
>
> to make a definite and serious decision to do something

Can the verb to resolve collocate with the noun [*situation*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/situation) which means:

> all of the facts, conditions, and events that affect someone or something at a particular time and in a particular place

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Hello, 206. How many Google hits does a search for "resolve this situation" generate? Do some of the first 10 say look like they use reasonable grammar?

Answer (score 2):

You may use it with confidence. Here's an example from 1931:

> [Historically, this situation is in no small measure due to the treaties, but the abrogation of the treaties would not now **resolve the situation**.](https://books.google.com/books?id=AWEvAAAAMAAJ&q=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&dq=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4xcT52K3QAhVC5yYKHSKbBH4Q6AEIHTAA)

And it reliably shows up decade after decade.

1947:

> [... proposals made by UNCIP [United Nations Commission on India and
>   Pakistan] and the Security Council to **resolve the situation**
>   created by Pakistan's aggression....](https://books.google.com/books?id=8bdPAQAAMAAJ&q=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&dq=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjirNDF663QAhXMSSYKHcRmApsQ6AEIIjAB)

1958:

> [... representative of Morocco declared that his country would
>   cooperate with OAU [Organization of African Unity] efforts to
>   **resolve the situation** peacefully](https://books.google.com/books?id=jrD8aukstAAC&pg=PA37&dq=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6nsTT7a3QAhWGNSYKHQwEC_44ChDoAQguMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&f=false)

1964:

> [It considers that a clear recognition of this threat by the Security
>   Council is imperative to enable the implementation of decisive
>   mandatory action which is required to **resolve the situation** before
>   all the possibilities of a peaceful solution are....](https://books.google.com/books?id=G75BAAAAIAAJ&q=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&dq=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfl7O37K3QAhWKNiYKHTXvCwE4ChDoAQgoMAM)

1972:

> [Both sets of questions are relevant to consensual children and, in
>   addition, the interaction of the two may mean coorientational concerns
>   come to the fore: How can I **resolve the situation** to my
>   satisfaction, and theirs?](https://books.google.com/books?id=9cducD7ZSaYC&pg=PA87&dq=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6nsTT7a3QAhWGNSYKHQwEC_44ChDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&f=false)

1986:

> [... talk to thesupervisor about it; or approach the staff members
>   again in an effort to better **resolve the situation**.](https://books.google.com/books?id=tN5sAAAAMAAJ&q=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&dq=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6nsTT7a3QAhWGNSYKHQwEC_44ChDoAQgkMAI)

1991:

> [Mendo's final attempt to **resolve the situation** puts the seal on
>   don Lope's death warrant.](https://books.google.com/books?id=mCwPRlepyBIC&pg=PA40&dq=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj87dbz7q3QAhVG5SYKHeaWAh0Q6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&f=false)

2000:

> [Strategically and constructively, the energy is used to **resolve the
>   situation.**](https://books.google.com/books?id=BVA4AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA189&dq=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilxuCX763QAhVD6SYKHfuYDXsQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=%22resolve%20the%20situation%22&f=false)

Comment: @Rathony Of course it will. The temptation to dis and  dismiss a rep-1 user far outweighs the willingness to learn interesting things about English usage.

Comment: Well, if this question had been asked 5 or 6 months ago, I would have advised the OP to include research, context, etc. But the OP is not even registered and I don't know how the OP will benefit from this answer. I just hope the OP will come back and read your answer to learn interesting things about English usage.

Comment: @Rathony My guess is that 206152 read "10 say look like" and fled for gentler climes. My other guess would have been that "resolve the situation" was part of '90s biz-speak for "fix a problem", but I would have been wrong.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter whether you would have been wrong. I think the key issue is the typo "if" and the link. I think if you wanted 206152 to learn more interesting things about English usage, you could have given more examples?

Comment: @Rathony *the typo* Oh, well played! And I missed it. Sorry.

Comment: @Rathony *more examples* Vivo ut serviam.

Comment: I edited the question. I am not sure if it will survive. Please feel free to edit it further.